# What are the next few "tetranacci-like" pseudoprimes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, computational-mathematics, pseudoprimes

Starting with $n=0$:

> $k=2$

Given the roots $x_i$ of $x^2-x-1=0$. Then, we have the *Lucas numbers*,

$$A_n = x_1^n+x_2^n = 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18,\dots$$

The $n$ that divides $A_n-1$ are all the primes and the *Lucas pseudoprimes*,

$$n = 705, 2465, 2737, 3745, 4181,\dots$$

> $k=3$

Given the roots $x_i$ of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$. Then,

$$B_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n = 3,1,3,7,11,21,39,\dots$$

The *tribonacci-like* pseudoprimes $n$ that divide $B_n-1$ are,

$$n = 182,25201,\color{brown}{233^2},63618,194390,750890,804055,\dots,\color{brown}{233^3},\dots$$

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148289/) for a list by S. Stadnicki.

> $k=4$

Given the roots $x_i$ of $x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1=0$. Then,

$$C_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+x_4^n = 4, 1, 3, 7, 15, 26, 51, 99,\dots$$

given by ([A073817](https://oeis.org/A073817)).  The *tetranacci-like* pseudoprimes $n$ that divide $C_n-1$ are,

$$n = 5^2,\,7^2,\,5^3,\,13^2,\,7^3,\,493,\,37^2,7825,\,29877\dots$$

and for $k=4$, these are all for $n<50000$.

> **Questions:**

1. What are the tetranacci-like pseudoprimes for $n<10^6$ or higher? (And which of them are squares or cubes?)
2. Why are the small tetranacci-like pseudoprimes powers of primes? (In contrast to the Lucas or tribonacci-like pseudoprimes.)