# Carmichael numbers of form $m^3+1$ and Ramanujan's $1729$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics, pseudoprimes

While researching for a post on [*tetranacci pseudoprimes*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268311/) I came across a list of *Carmichael numbers*,

$$C_n = 561,\, 1105,\, 1729,\, 2465,\, 2821,\dots$$

Of course, *Ramanujan's taxicab number* $1729 = 12^3+1$ stood out. So I looked at other near-cubes $C(m) = m^3+1$ and found that for $n<10000$, there were six, namely,

$$m = 12,\, 36,\, 138,\, 270,\, 4800,\, 7560,\dots?$$

$C(m) = m^3+1 = (m+1)(m^2-m+1)$ have the factorizations,

$$C(12) = 7 \cdot \color{brown}{13} \cdot 19$$

$$C(36) = 13 \cdot \color{brown}{37} \cdot 97$$

$$C(138) = 7 \cdot 37 \cdot 73 \cdot \color{brown}{139}$$

$$C(270) = 13 \cdot 37 \cdot 151 \cdot \color{brown}{271}$$

$$C(4800) = 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 151 \cdot \color{brown}{4801}$$

$$C(7560) = 271 \cdot 433 \cdot 487 \cdot \color{brown}{7561}$$

Note that $m+1$ is prime.

> **Questions:**

1. Since there are an infinite number of Carmichael numbers, what others are of form $m^3+1$?
2. Is it true that if it is of form $m^3+1$, then $m+1$ is prime?

**P.S.** Richard Pinch's [database](http://www.chalcedon.demon.co.uk/rgep/carpsp.html) with $C_n<10^{21}$ seem to have broken links.

$\color{brown}{Update}$: Courtesy of R. Pinch's answer, the *complete* list with $C_n<10^{21}$ include three more,

$$C(12840)$$

$$C(14700)$$

$$C(678480)$$

and only $14700+1$ is composite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first few Carmichael numbers of the form $m^3+1$ are

```
 1729
 46657
 2628073
 19683001
 110592000001
 432081216001
 2116874304001
 3176523000001
 312328165704192001
```

The eighth in the list, which is $C_{12616}$, has a composite value of $m+1$.

BTW, my tables are currently at http://s369624816.websitehome.co.uk/