# What is the Fibonacci-like sequence called where one sums the last 3 numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci-sequence is defined like.

$F_{x+1} = F_{x} + F_{x-1}; F_0 = 0, F_1=1, x \in {\Bbb N}$

Is there a special name for this sequence:

$F_{x+1} = F_{x} + F_{x-1} + F_{x-2}$ ?

Which?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers

Comment: As [discussed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/fibonacci-tribonacci-and-other-similar-sequences), this is often called the *tribonacci* sequence.

Comment: Both of you are right. Thanks. as @JackD'Aurizio was the first... Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence given by $T_0=1,T_1=T_2=1$ and $T_{n+3}=T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}+T_n$ is usually called the [*tribonacci* sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html). It shares many properties with the Fibonacci sequence (like the existence of a Zeckendorf-like theorem) but obviously has a different characteristic polynomial, $x^3-x^2-x-1$.

Comment: According to your link T_2=2 not 1. Which makes sense because if it was 1 then T_2 != T_0+T_1

Comment: Well, a shift of index does not affect the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

There are higher fibonacci sequences. The one you mentioned is called a Tribonacci. Higher ones are Tetranacci, Pentanacci, Hexanacci, Heptanacci, etc. You can either recursively generate the sequence or use a characteristic polynomial for each. More info here (at the bottom of page): http://www.genautica.com/math/naccis/fibonacci_and_higher_order_naccis.html

To get the first 100 numbers of your Tribonacci with Python, you could do something like this:

```
list1=[1,2,3]

for _ in xrange(4,101):
    list1.append(list1[-3]+list1[-2]+list1[-1])

print list1
```